# Regex - search match for specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to look for an instance of a string in a textbox/textarea value i have attached my code so far:

```js
$('.message-contents').on('keyup',function(){
  textbox_value = $(this).val();
  //working on code
        var regex = /#{\w.*}/;

 //working on http://regex101.com
//var regex = /^#{\w.*}$/;

window.variable_found = 0
     if(textbox_value.match(regex)!= null){
      console.log('found');
      variable_length = ($(this).val().trim().length);
      console.log(variable_length);
      window.variable_found = variable_length ;

     }
     else{
      console.log('not found');
      
     }
});
```

```html
<textarea class="message-contents"></textarea>
```

This works however it also counts for the succeeding input of strings as well. How can I modify my code to give me the desired result below:

```
#{string}asasasasas = 9 //desired output;
#{string}asasasasas = 19//current output
```

I want to get the length of the string starting from the '#{' and ending at '}'. Based on the desired output which is 9.

Comment: describe in words what do you want to achieve. your regex is invalid at all(unescaped `{` and `}` should define repeating count but you have regexp inside) so there is no way to realize what's the goal

Comment: edits to the original post has been made

Comment: so you just need to take some string and find all matches inside the textarea value - is that it?

Comment: yes and to return their lengths without the succeeding string inputs just the ones on this string '#{string}'

Comment: I still don't understand. Say once you are checking for occurrences of "abcd" - what length do you expect? is not it 4? could you please provide more samples of "input data+expected result"?

Comment: abcd should not be considered since it does not match the pattern however if you input it as #{abcd} then a match should be found. returning the length which is 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not access the match result properly. Try it like that:

```js
$('.message-contents').on('keyup',function(){
  textbox_value = $(this).val();
        var regex = /#{\w.*}/;

      // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
     if((m = regex.exec(textbox_value)) !== null){
      console.log('found');
      variable_length = m[0].length;
      console.log(variable_length);
     }
     else{
      console.log('not found');      
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="message-contents"></textarea>
```

Comment: why did you use exec instead of match?

Comment: Citing from MDN: if you want to obtain capture groups and the global flag is set, you need to use RegExp.exec() instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: You could use `.match` here too as long as you retrieve the matched value.

Comment: hmm I could not get it to work for .match so Im tagging your answer as correct.